# htaccess redirect not existing file (404) as 302 to another location

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Doing pagination on a site through lazy load:

I would want to redirect

```
dir/546/index.html
```

if it does not exist

to

```
 /dir/index.html
```

`546/` is of any numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule in your **`/dir/.htaccess`** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/(index\.html)$ $1 [L,NC]
```